# How do I update JList and store into an array using a function?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jlist

I am under the impression that most of my code work, however, I think I am confident that I am only missing one line under the function `updatedJList()` Please help, thank you.

```
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.JList;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Ex1 extends JFrame {

    private JTextField txtName;
    private JList nameList;
    private String[] nameArr;
    private int arrCounter = 0;
    private JLabel lblDisplayName;

    public Ex1(){

        this.setTitle("Exercise01");
        this.setSize(300, 266);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        this.nameArr = new String[10];
        JLabel lblName = new JLabel("Name:");
        lblName.setBounds(10, 11, 264, 14);
        getContentPane().add(lblName);

        this.txtName = new JTextField();
        this.txtName.setBounds(10, 25, 264, 20);
        getContentPane().add(this.txtName);
        this.txtName.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnAddName = new JButton("Add Name to List");
        btnAddName.setBounds(10, 49, 264, 23);
        getContentPane().add(btnAddName);
        btnAddName.addActionListener(new AddNameListener());

        //Create ScrollPane

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 75, 264, 126);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

       //Create and Add JList

        this.nameList = new JList();
        nameList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        this.updateJList();

        this.nameList.addListSelectionListener(new DisplayListener());
        this.lblDisplayName = new JLabel("(Name will be shown here)");
        this.lblDisplayName.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        this.lblDisplayName.setBounds(10, 203, 264, 14);
        getContentPane().add(this.lblDisplayName);

        this.setVisible(true);
}

    private class AddNameListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        updateJList();

    }
}

    private void updateJList(){
        //I think I am missing something on this line.. HELP
        String name = this.txtName.getText();
        this.txtName.setText(name);
        this.arrCounter++;
        this.txtName.setText("");
        DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
        for(int i =0;i<this.nameArr.length;i++)
        {
            model.addElement(name);
        }
        this.nameList.setModel(model);
    }
    private class DisplayListener implements ListSelectionListener {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {
    displayName();
    }
    }
    private void displayName()
    {
    int index = this.nameList.getSelectedIndex();
    String name = this.nameArr[index];
    this.lblDisplayName.setText(name);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Ex1 gui = new Ex1();
    }
    }
```

I am very very very lost at this point, I cant seem to figure out what's wrong, I've been learning Java for about 8 weeks now, and I've also been working on this question for 4 hours. I really think I am missing a line, but if you think otherwise, please feel free to comment. Thank you, wonderful people!

**Edit:**
After some discussion the issue that the OP is stating is the following:

> Whenever I run the code, it will work, however, when I key in the name in the text box to store it in the array and display it, it will not show up in the text box, therefore I cannot display the name.

Comment: @GauravMall, Hi! I stated I was having an issue with the updatedJList(); function. Thanks!

Comment: @GauravMall Whenever I run the code, it will work, however, when i key in the name in the text box to store it in the array and display it, it will not show up in the text box, therefore i cannot display the name.. :)

Comment: Great. Now we can see what the issue is and fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the below code with that in your question. The changes are described after the code.

```java
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.JList;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Ex1 extends JFrame {

    private JTextField txtName;
    private JList<Object> nameList;
    private String[] nameArr;
    private int arrCounter = 0;
    private JLabel lblDisplayName;

    public Ex1() {

        this.setTitle("Exercise01");
        this.setSize(300, 266);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        this.nameArr = new String[10];
        JLabel lblName = new JLabel("Name:");
        lblName.setBounds(10, 11, 264, 14);
        getContentPane().add(lblName);

        this.txtName = new JTextField();
        this.txtName.setBounds(10, 25, 264, 20);
        getContentPane().add(this.txtName);
        this.txtName.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnAddName = new JButton("Add Name to List");
        btnAddName.setBounds(10, 49, 264, 23);
        getContentPane().add(btnAddName);
        btnAddName.addActionListener(new AddNameListener());

        // Create and Add JList

        DefaultListModel<Object> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
        this.nameList = new JList<>(model);
        nameList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        // Create ScrollPane

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(nameList);
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 75, 264, 126);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

        this.nameList.addListSelectionListener(new DisplayListener());
        this.lblDisplayName = new JLabel("(Name will be shown here)");
        this.lblDisplayName.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        this.lblDisplayName.setBounds(10, 203, 264, 14);
        getContentPane().add(this.lblDisplayName);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class AddNameListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            updateJList();
        }
    }

    private void updateJList() {
        // I think I am missing something on this line.. HELP
        String name = this.txtName.getText();
        this.txtName.setText(name);
        this.arrCounter++;
        this.txtName.setText("");
        DefaultListModel<Object> model = (DefaultListModel<Object>) nameList.getModel();
        model.addElement(name);
    }

    private class DisplayListener implements ListSelectionListener {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {
            displayName();
        }
    }

    private void displayName() {
        int index = this.nameList.getSelectedIndex();
        if (index >= 0) {
            ListModel<Object> model = nameList.getModel();
            Object obj = model.getElementAt(index);
            String name = obj == null ? "" : obj.toString();
            this.lblDisplayName.setText(name);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ex1 gui = new Ex1();
    }
}
```

Create a model for the `JList` first and pass it to the `JList` constructor.

```java
DefaultListModel<Object> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
this.nameList = new JList<>(model);
```

You are adding an empty `JScrollPane`. You need to pass the `JList` to the `JScrollPane` constructor.

```java
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(nameList);
```

In method `updateJList()`, you don't need a new model, you just need to update the existing model by adding an element to it.

```java
DefaultListModel<Object> model = (DefaultListModel<Object>) nameList.getModel();
model.addElement(name);
```

### EDIT

Excuse me, I didn't pay attention to that part of your code that displays the selected value from `nameList`.

I changed method `displayName()` in the above code to the following:

```java
private void displayName() {
    int index = this.nameList.getSelectedIndex();
    if (index >= 0) {
        ListModel<Object> model = nameList.getModel();
        Object obj = model.getElementAt(index);
        String name = obj == null ? "" : obj.toString();
        this.lblDisplayName.setText(name);
    }
}
```

You don't need `nameArr` and you don't need `arrCounter`.

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much. It displays the name, but now, my displayName(); function no longer works, I wonder in what way I can change it.

Comment: Hey Abra, Thank you so much, this works now, however if I could trouble you with what this line means *String name = obj == null ? "" : obj.toString();*,  if not, thank you so much :)

Comment: Google for the words ___java ternary operator___ Also refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for an Array.

When you use Swing components, the data is store in a "model", in this case the `DefaultListModel`. So the data is added to the model and if you every want to access the data in the JList you get the data from the model.

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
```

That code is wrong. You don't want to keep creating a new model every time you click on the button. You want to add items to the existing model so all the items can be displayed.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). The `ListDemo` code will show you how to better structure your class so you can dynamically add and remove items in the model. So download the code and modify it for your requirements.